# How can I send a big file from the browser to the Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to send from the client to the server an image using `data: URL`. My functions to read the uploaded image and send data to the server are very simple:

```
getTags = event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
      return;
    }

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (theFile => {
      return (e) => {
        this.sendDataToServer(e.target.result, theFile.type);
      };
    })(file);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

sendDataToServer = (data, fileType) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': fileType,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({data}),
      cache: 'default'
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/img', options)
    .then(res =>  res.text())
    .then(body => {
        console.log(body);
    });
  }
```

If I print `e.target.result` before put it into `sendDataToServer` I see a valid `data: URL`.

So, my server:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/img', (req, res, next) => {
  const data = decodeURIComponent(req.body.data);
  console.log(data);
  // ...
```

But in Chrome DevTools in Network tab, I see:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/img
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Remote Address:52.15.183.149:80
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Date:Sat, 25 Mar 2017 20:18:09 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:b580f823.ngrok.io
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.1165
```

On the server my `console.log` just print `undefined`. Can't understand why it's happened. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in the question showing the client-side info indicates it’s working OK from the client side.

So it seems like there must be some problem on the server side not caused by any client error.

I say that because:

1. The devtools snippet for the request shows `Request Method:OPTIONS`, [which is expected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) since your `POST` has a `Content-Type` header other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, 
   `multipart/form-data`,
   or `text/plain`.
2. In that case, your browser first sends a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request and expects to get back a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type` response header along with an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` including `POST`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
3. The devtools snippet in the question shows it gets all those as expected, so it should then be sending the actual `POST`. You don’t show a devtools snippet for that `POST` but if your browser were not doing the actual `POST` it would be logging some kind of error to the devtools console.

So unless I’m missing something, there are no mistakes in your client-side code, thus there instead must be some problem on the server side that’s causing it to fail.